# How do I load multiple grayscale images as a single tensor in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm currently trying to use a stack a set of images as a single entity for each label to train a CNN on using cross-validation. Given a dataset of 224x224x1 grayscale images sorted by:

```
Root/
    Class0/image0_view0.png
    Class0/image0_view1.png
    Class0/image0_view2.png
    ...
    Class1/image0_view0.png
    Class1/image0_view1.png
    Class1/image0_view2.png
```

How would I go about flowing 3 images (view 0, 1, and 2) as a single tensor with dimensions 224x224x3 (3 grayscale images)? In other words, how would I create a dataset of image stacks in pytorch using ImageFolder/DatasetFolder and DataLoader? Would I have to re-organize my folders and classes, or would it be easier to make the stacks when I make the splits for cross-validation?

Thank you for your time and help! Let me know if I can provide any more info.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You want the channels of your image to be other images? If I know the reason I might be able to direct you better. It seems like what you want may not require pytorch at all. You just need to read in the images and stack them and then save them as a new image with 3 channels.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I want to do this because each label isn't always seen on one image alone, and when I tried montaging all 3 images to one image, the CNN didn't perform so well either.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds to me like you have a classification problem where the class may only be seen from 1 of 3 'views' of the same object. Instead of merging the images together and trying to classify, I might suggest just generating classifications for all 3 images individually and then merging the predictions into one. So if view0 had class 1 predicted and view1 had none and view2 had class 2 predicted, the overall prediction would be classes 1 and 2.

Comment: These labels were generated for an image set, so while it's definitely possible to do your suggestion, it'd be more time consuming and more computationally expensive. What are the concerns you have for image stacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar task. I needed to load a random sequence of 3 images as an element of a batch for training the network not on separate images but on seq of images. For batch size 8, I have 8 x 3 = 24 images. This seems to be very similar to different views in your case. I used imread_collection functionality from skimage.io. I added such a **getitem** to the Dataset class:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
    idx_q = int(torch.randint(0 + self.boundary, self.length - self.boundary, (1,))) 
    
    q = imread_collection([self.image_paths[idx_q-1], self.image_paths[idx_q], self.image_paths[idx_q+1]], conserve_memory=True)
            
    if self.transform:
        q = torch.stack([self.transform(img) for img in q])

    return q, p, n
```

Here I generate a random index of an image and then load three consecutive images using imread_collection and self.image_paths, which is the list with paths to all images. Then I do transform of each image and stack them. In your case, you should think about using the right indexes, maybe by applying a sliding window on the length of self.image_paths.

A bit more info could be found on the [torch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-dataloader-dataset-to-load-several-samples-at-once/19766/11). I also tried to ask and find a more elegant solution, but couldn't and successfully trained the model with such an approach.

Answer (score -2):

> How do I load multiple grayscale images as a single tensor in pytorch?

In general, the number of channels is not important.

The operation known as "loading a batch of data" is what you need. For this PyTorch has  [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) class. `DataLoader` class further needs `Dataset` class.

If in `DataLoader` the batch size is 64 (bs=64) you will load 64 images from once as tensor.

If you use [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) this will not return minibatch for you. `ImageFolder` is a `Dataset` derived class.

The problem with `ImageFolder` (if you just use that) is you will get a single image per index. You would combine multiple images to a minibatch then.

Here is one example using `ImageFolder` with CIFAR10 data.

```
from torchvision import transforms
imagef = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(r'C:\Users\dj\data\cifar10\test', transform=transforms.ToTensor())

print(imagef)
print(imagef.classes)
img, label = imagef[0]
display(img)
print(img.size())
print(label)
```

Out:

```
Dataset ImageFolder
    Number of datapoints: 10000
    Root location: C:\Users\dj\data\cifar10\test
    StandardTransform
Transform: ToTensor()
['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

tensor([[[0.6078, 0.6549, 0.6902,  ..., 0.7882, 0.7922, 0.7529],
         [0.6000, 0.6392, 0.6706,  ..., 0.7922, 0.7961, 0.7412],
         [0.6078, 0.6275, 0.6588,  ..., 0.8078, 0.8000, 0.7412],
         ...,
         [0.3490, 0.2235, 0.2392,  ..., 0.3490, 0.2314, 0.2627],
         [0.3490, 0.2353, 0.2471,  ..., 0.2235, 0.2392, 0.2941],
         [0.3608, 0.2353, 0.2392,  ..., 0.2353, 0.2510, 0.2863]], ...


torch.Size([3, 32, 32])
0
```

The next example is based on `DataLoader`:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms
import PIL.Image as Image

def pil_loader(path):    
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        img = Image.open(f)
        return img.convert('RGB')

ds = torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder(r'C:\Users\dj\data\cifar10\test', 
                                        loader=pil_loader, 
                                        extensions=('.png'), 
                                        transform=transforms.ToTensor())
dl = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=2)
len(dl)
for imgs,lbls in dl:    
    print(imgs.size()) # torch.Size([2, 3, 32, 32])
    break
```

This `DataLoader` is what you may need. The one I present, has the custom loading function: `pil_loader`.

You can also use `ImageFolder` instead of `DatasetFolder` in the previous example.

That would be something like:

```
ds =  torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(r'C:\Users\dj\data\cifar10\test', transform=transforms.ToTensor())
dl = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=3)
print(len(dl))

for imgs,lbls in dl:    
    print(imgs.size())
    break
```

Comment: I don't think using batches will solve the problem here. It seems OP would want to pass all 3 images as a single input that goes into the network and generates a single label. In the case of batches, that will result in a number of predictions equal to batch size.